# Problems displaying some characters

Tags: php, html, xml, character-encoding

I've got an XML file from which I've extracted the following text -

> The Sansa Clip+ MP3 player gives you
>   more to enjoy.  Enjoy up to 2,000
>   songs†† with an 8GB* player, FM radio,
>   long-life battery and voice recorder.
>   PLUS now even more!  Expand your
>   enjoyment when you add in preloaded
>   content cards** into the new memory
>   card slot, including slotRadio™ and
>   slotMusic™ cards**.  Or, save your own
>   music, podcasts, and audio books onto
>   a microSD™/microSDHC™ memory card** to
>   expand your play.It’s brought to you
>   by SanDisk with awesome sound to enjoy
>   your music.  Just clip it on and enjoy
>   more music with an incredible 15
>   hours† battery-fueled fun.  See what
>   you’re listening to with the bright,
>   easy-to-read screen and intuitively
>   searchable menus. Color your world in
>   red, blue or sleek black undertones.

Why does it display on my webpage as below and how can I fix it automatically? Thanks.

> The Sansa Clip+Â MP3 playerÂ gives you more to enjoy.Â  Enjoy up to 2,000 songsâ€ â€  with an 8GB* player, FM radio, long-life battery and voice recorder. PLUS now even more! Expand your enjoyment when you add in preloaded content cards** into the new memory card slot, including slotRadioâ„¢ and slotMusicâ„¢ cards**. Or, save your own music, podcasts, and audio books onto a microSDâ„¢/microSDHCâ„¢ memory card** to expand your play.Itâ€™s brought to you by SanDisk with awesome sound to enjoy your music. Just clip it on and enjoy more music with an incredible 15 hoursâ€  battery-fueled fun. See what youâ€™re listening to with the bright, easy-to-read screen and intuitively searchable menus. Color your world in red, blue or sleek black undertones.

NOTE: I tried preinheimer's suggestion,

First I tested it with a text file which worked well.

```
$content = file_get_contents("test.txt");

echo htmlentities($content);
```

But when I tried the same thing dynamically it didn't work and left the text just the same.

```
$content = $responseTemp->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview[$j]->Content;

echo htmlentities($content);
```

They both contain the same text but for some reason the dynamically version doesn't work.

ANOTHER UPDATE: I tried Juan's suggestion which is a slight improvement but still doesn't reproduce correctly, replacing many charecters with a question mark. 
Here's what it gives me,

> The Sansa Clip+ MP3 player gives you
>   more to enjoy.  Enjoy up to 2,000
>   songs?? with an 8GB* player, FM radio,
>   long-life battery and voice recorder.
>   PLUS now even more! Expand your
>   enjoyment when you add in preloaded
>   content cards** into the new memory
>   card slot, including slotRadio? and
>   slotMusic? cards**. Or, save your own
>   music, podcasts, and audio books onto
>   a microSD?/microSDHC? memory card** to
>   expand your play.It?s brought to you
>   by SanDisk with awesome sound to enjoy
>   your music. Just clip it on and enjoy
>   more music with an incredible 15
>   hours? battery-fueled fun. See what
>   you?re listening to with the bright,
>   easy-to-read screen and intuitively
>   searchable menus. Color your world in
>   red, blue or sleek black undertones.

FINAL UPDATE: Aha, my mistake, I replaced $myOutputEncoding with 'utf-8' on Juan's example and add the following in the head tags to get it working,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: the page http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php has some good examples, but I don't have the time right now to try them and figure out which is the best way.

Comment: I tried htmlentities(myContent) which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you dont know the original encoding, you can try guessing with `mb_detect_encoding` like so

```
$content = $responseTemp->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview[$j]->Content;
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding( $content );

$encodedText = mb_convert_encoding( $content, $myOutputEncoding, $encoding );
```

where `$myOutputEncoding` is the encoding you use. Then when you output `$encodedText` it should show the text correctly.

Comment: How do I decide what the encoding should be?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a character set issue.
Luckily, I wrote an article that got published today.
http://phpadvent.org/2009/character-sets-by-paul-reinheimer

Check for a character set in the XML document (should be at the top, probably UTF-8), then try serving your page with the same character set.

Comment: I just checked, the xml file doesn't seem to have a character set. Its a response from amazon's AWS.

Comment: how about the Content-Type response header, it sometimes includes charset